# Stock Nexus 7 2013 stuck at "Google" when booting

Tags: nexus-7, stock-android, unbricking

stock Nexus 7 2013 4G stuck at "Google" when booting.

I can go to bootloader using `Power + Vol Down` but failed when going to recovery. it goes to "Google" again instead of Android icon.

I also tried to unlock bootloader and [flashing](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en#razorg) [5.1.0 (LMY47O)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/razorg-lmy47o-factory-4fa870e1.tgz) and [5.1.1 (LMY47V)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/razorg-lmy47v-factory-f230ab31.tgz) but both still stuck at "Google" logo and cannot go into recovery mode.

Similar threads with no success:

- [Nexus 7 stucks at Google logo](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/100791/5229)
- https://youtu.be/BsDElKLoMV0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH!! Unexpectedly now it works!! Here's roughly what I did:

- Flash 5.1.1, & leave it to try to do normal boot => failed
- try to go to recovery => failed
- flash 5.1.0, & leave it to try to do normal boot => failed
- try to go to recovery => failed
- flash 5.1.1, & leave it to try to do normal boot => success! but very slow process!

make sure when flashing stock images all steps are successful in the command line, e.g. formatting, updating (some missing .sig files are okay)

Answer (score 0):

I inserted a SIM card, and selected Start from the boot loader menu (power + volume up menu), and it booted right up.